# OLS error while loading shared libraries libargon2.so.0

Tags: php, litespeed

I am a newbie in Openlitespeed and while configuring OpenLiteSpeed to run my wordpress website, I checked the error.log and found out this error:

`No request delivery notification has been received from LSAPI application, possible dead lock`

and here it is the content of my stderr.log

`/usr/local/lsws/lsphp73/bin/lsphp: error while loading shared libraries: libargon2.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Answer (score 0):

It means your OS/System need libargon2 package but not exist.

For Debian/Ubuntu, please run

```
apt-get update -y
apt-get install -y libargon2-0
```

For CentOS, please run

```
yum install epel-release
```

Best

Comment: I changed the php version to lsphp71 and the problem resolved.

Comment: I did that and it says it's already installed and latest version.

Comment: @AmirRazoR if the issue is still reproducible, maybe you can contact with support@litespeedtech.com for further check and update the result here.